# How to stay motivated after changing field for one I'm less keen on?

Tags: career-development

A year ago, I had my first job as a mobile developer. Now that the project is finished, I'll be taking on web projects with my team of course.

The issue is, I am not passionate about web. I don't hate it, it's just that mobile is my forte. I am always excited learning something new and advancing my tech skills in mobile. I also love learning new things outside mobile to broaden my skills but not as excited when in mobile though.

I realize that I am losing my motivation. I don't know, I feel like I care less about the project compared to when I was doing mobile. I am being practical, so I just don't want to leave my job. It's my first programming job.

I think my take here is how do you keep your self motivated if you are not as passionate on what you do?

Now I know some will advice to leave and find a job, but I am on a small city and considering what's going on around the world being laid off, leaving my job is not an option and I am very thankful having a job. I just want to get some advice staying motivated on their job even though it is not their passion. Anyone?

Comment: Are there others in the company working on mobile or is there just no mobile work around?

Comment: There are some but most require 3 years and above experience and not a lot of companies anymore hire a native mobile dev if they do they look for intermediate to senior level. I am just starting on my career. Felt like I missed the boat on mobile dev when it was still hot, though I  really like mobile dev.

Comment: oh, I meant in the company you are currently in. Are you the only mobile dev?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. No, there is a senior mobile dev but he's assigned to a different project that is mobile related. They only need 1 mobile dev on that project so yeah.

Comment: Would be nice why I get downvoted.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Workplace.SE ! I rephrased your title so it's more on topic here, corrected some mistakes and formatted better your question. The downvote may have been because with the previous title it was a bit off-topic. Feel free to tell me if you want me to revert my changes.

Comment: Is it fair to say that this maybe a case of taking the rough with the smooth? you say that you love being and working on projects that require a mobile dev but hate doing the web side of things, i think some good motivation would be to think that once you have finished with the web side of things, you will return to another project involving mobile development.

Comment: @LP154 Wow thanks for taking the time to do that :D really appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Now

You've already recognized that your options are limited at the moment. As Joe says, you may want to just focus on your paycheck until other options open up.

It might also help to think about your current work in another way.
Web dev has a lot of common points with mobile dev, so you could think of your current project as building your fundamentals. A lot of web dev projects often spin off into mobile (or at least mobile support) projects as well!

#### Moving forward

If it's possible, mention to your boss that web dev is not a direction that you would like to continue moving forward in. I would suggest doing this towards the end of your current project--and that you finish at least one project!

The worst case scenario is that your current company can't help you and you will have to change in the future. Hopefully the world situation will be better at that point.

---

In short, be patient, but proactive.
You're probably not wasting your time and there are steps you can take for the future, so keep your eyes open.

Answer (score 3):

> how do you keep your self motivated if you are not as passionate on
> what you do?

If you can't just muster passion for doing a good, professional job in whatever is assigned to you, then concentrate on the paycheck you receive. That should provide sufficient motivation.

There were difficult times when I looked at my wife and children and understood why I continued to work hard.

Comment: That sounds like the most effective way to frustration and "inner resignation"

Comment: +1.  Most people don’t have the privilege of having a job that’s their ultimate passion.  Getting a paycheck and a basic pride in yourself and your work should be sufficient.

Comment: " Most people don’t have the privilege of having a job that’s their ultimate passion " this, if you live pretty much anywhere outside of US/Europe bubble you just play with cards you are dealt with, no-brainer for me.

Answer (score 0):

It simply is too hard and unlikely to land a dream job, otherwise we would see bulk of the worlds population working as actors, astronauts, musicians, jet pilots, models, athletes and what not. I never liked management and always considered it bureaucratic gimmick, but now I am actively trying to make a jump from CS/academia to management despite that former is the closest one to my dream job.
Sometimes we all just set our sentiments aside and look where stability and better prospect lies, especially when we reach certain point and start trading ambition and vigor for wisdom and safe future. This is the simple, down to earth truth.